# Enable button (or any element) if at least one input has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm need to enable a button (and perhaps other elements on the form in the near future) if at least one of the input element has values. I'm using BootstrapValidator as a main validation library since I'm using Twitter Bootstrap but have not idea, in the easy way, to achieve this. What I know is check each input one by one as for example:

```
if ($('.some_input').length > 0) { // then do actions }
```

But if I have many fields this solutions seems to be tedious and not very practical, also I'll need to trigger in some many events as for example: `keypress`, `keyup`, `keydown`, `blur` and maybe others too (not clear at all).

Right now the form is pretty simple as image shows below and the my solution should works but the form will grow up fast and in the near future so I leave it behind and I'm looking for another solution.

[image: 2014-10-16_11-16-24]

Here the button "Buscar" (it's enabled on the img but doesn't care about this I miss to disabled when I took the screenshoot) should be enabled only if any of the input on the form (Codigo de la Norma, Año de Publicacion, Palabra o Termino que contiene la Norma) has values and possibly a choice marked on the select below has a value different from the default (can be any as for example --Pick one-- with value=0) in a simple words: any input has at least 3 characters minimmum and choice in the SELECT should be different from the default one, how can I do that?

Comment: Instead of using key events use jQuery's `$('.commonclass').on('change', function() { handle here });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $(function() {
            $(':text').on('input', function() {
                if( $(':text').filter(function() { return !!this.value; }).length > 0 ) {
                     $('button').prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                     $('button').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    <button disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Update**

To expand this so it works with other form elements (excluding `radios` and `checks`) you can change `:text` to `:input`. And the code can be shortened to the following:

```
$(function() {
    $(':input').on('input', function() {
        var completed = $(':input').filter(function() { return !!this.value; }).length > 0;
        $('button').prop('disabled', !completed);
    });
});
```

Comment: This almost work, but is missing the SELECT behavior in order to check if the SELECT has changed from default value to any other option, I could use the same `change` event as mentioned in the post above but how to fit in your solution?

Comment: Just change `:text` to `:input` and that should do it!!

Comment: Yes, this is the same I did but if you change the SELECT element from the default `Age range` to any the button isn't enabled

Comment: Are we looking at the same demo? Which browser and version are you using? Works for me in the latest Chrome and I don't see why it should not work in other modern ones. Do you have a demo where it does not work?

Comment: Well you're right it works on Chrome I tested a while ago but in Firefox 33 it doesn't, can you try on this one? and I'm using the demo you leave on the fiddle

Comment: Give me a minute so I can leave the demo of my own code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63190/discussion-between-user3558931-and-reynierpm).

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413139/toggle-button-enabled-disabled-if-at-least-one-input-has-values-or-if-a-select-c)

Answer (score 1):

Each `input` element has an event called `change` attached to it. I would add a function to run whenever this is done.

If you **really** want to run code whenever even one letter is added to a field, you can instead use the event known as `input` (be sure to check the performance of any code like this though, as it will be triggered alot!)

Although, there is much less browser support for the `input` event than the `change` one.

```js
$('input.some_input').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) { 
    alert('woot! text!');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='some_input' value='test' />
```