# Toggle button enabled/disabled if at least one input has values or if a select changes the default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412329/enable-button-or-any-element-if-at-least-one-input-has-value/) related topic where a user leave a solution and it works, I come with a second part where I forgot to mention that the SELECT element has a `.select2()` applied. If you test a live example here on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/omdpfzvy/) you'll see how the `button#btnBuscar` is enable any time a input change and gets values or when `SELECT` changes the default option but if I delete the values from the INPUTs or choice back the default option in the SELECT then the button is not disabled, where is the error on the solution provided:

```
$(':input').on('input change', function () {
    var completed = $(':input').filter(function () {
        return !!this.value;
    }).length > 0;
    $('button#btnBuscar').prop('disabled', !completed);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your could change:

```
<option selected="selected" value="-1">-- SELECCIONAR --</option>
```

To:

```
<option selected="selected" value="">-- SELECCIONAR --</option>
```

OR adjust the js code to:

```
$(function(){
    $('select.toSelect2').select2();

    $(':input').on('input change', function () {
        var completed = $(':input').filter(function () {
            return !!this.value && !$(this).is('select') || 
                   (this).is('select') && +this.value > -1;
        }).length > 0;
        $('button#btnBuscar').prop('disabled', !completed);
    });        
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/omdpfzvy/5/)

Comment: Sorry i have to make adjustments to the JS logic.

Comment: Yes, I notice that when you type something on the `:text` (inputs) the button is not enabled

Comment: All set now. Check it out now :) Enjoy!